# Pass an html textbox value to innerhtml textbox

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, dom

I have a dynamic table where the data are being saved as an array in the database. I have a textbox from my html form which generates random numbers and I want to pass that textbox value from my html form to my dynamic table (pure javascript) and be saved into my database with the same value from the textbox's form.

```js
function addRow(){
 var table = document.getElementById("bod");
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 
 row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
 row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = document.getElementById("field10").value; //this should be in textbox form with field10's value
 
}
```

```html
<input type = "text" name = "field10" id = "field10" readonly = "true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this... It's not pretty, but it's a start.

```js
function addRow(){
 var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 
 row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
 row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = document.getElementById("new-row").value;
}
```

```html
<input id="new-row" />
<button id="add" onclick="javascript:addRow()">Add Row</button>
<hr/>
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

Comment: new-row should be in textbox form @Joshua McClure